# Query com dois somatórios para a mesma coluna

Tags: sql, query, mysql

É possível fazer uma query em que nessa mesma consulta sejam executadas duas somas sobre a mesma coluna?

O que eu tenho é o seguinte:

**Somatório total das vendas**

```
select month(emitido_date) as mes, ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0) as total
from documento as doc
inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3  and doc.rascunho = false and doc.exercicio_id = 4 
group by mes
order by mes
```

**Somatório vendas Liquidadas**

```
select month(emitido_date) as mes, ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0) as total
from documento as doc
inner join documento_serie as serie on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
inner join documento_detail as det on doc.id = det.documento_id
inner join phos_iva as iva on iva.id = det.iva_id
where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3  and doc.rascunho = false and doc.exercicio_id = 4 and (serie.documento_tipo_id = 10 or serie.documento_tipo_id = 11 or serie.documento_tipo_id = 15)
group by mes
order by mes
```

***1ª questão. É possível ter o retorno de uma tabela |Mês|totalVendas|totalLiquidado|  tudo apenas numa query?***

***2ª questão. Na segunda query apresentada, na cláusula `where`, quando o campo `serie.documento_tipo_id` for 15, no `inner join` da tabela `documento_detail` o campo não poderá ser o `doc.id` mas sim o `doc.source_id`. Como poderei colocar esta condição?***

Comment: Já testaste essas *query's*?

Comment: Sim essas query's estão a funcionar, só na segunda é que não soma o valor caso o documento seja do tipo 15.

Comment: Hugo muda o 15 de lugar com o 11 e verifica se deixa de somar os documentos do tipo 11.

Comment: Sim deixa somar os 11, só não soma o 15 como explicado na 2ª questão.

Comment: experimenta com `and serie.documento_categoria_id IN(10,11,15)`

Comment: Estou em mysql e esse IN dá erro. Não sei se o que direi ajudará, mas o doc 15 não tem nada que lhe corresponde na tabela documento_detail, sendo assim, só consegue ir buscar o seu valor pelo doc.source_id

Comment: Então é normal que não some nada.

Comment: Sim é normal que não some nada, mas eu quero que some, porque o seu valor vem do doc.source_id nesse caso específico.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26834/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-hugo-machado).

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível fazer isto sem recorrer a uma subquery.

- Como as "Vendas Liquidadas" são um sub-conjunto do "Total de Vendas" deves usar a primeiro query como base para o que desejas.
- Usa um **CASE** para restringir as vendas no cálculo do total "Vendas Liquidadas"
- Para a condição "quando o campo serie.documento_tipo_id for 15, no inner join da tabela documento_detail o campo não poderá ser o doc.id mas sim o doc.source_id" basta, uma vez mais, usar um **CASE**.

No final a query ficaria assim:

```
select month(emitido_date) as mes, 
      ifnull(sum((det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100))),0) as totalVendas,
      ifnull(sum(case when serie.documento_tipo_id in (10, 11, 15) then (det.preco * det.quantidade) * (iva.valor/100) + (det.preco * det.quantidade) - (det.preco * det.quantidade * (det.desconto/100)) else 0 end),0) as totalLiquidado       
from documento as doc
inner join documento_serie as serie 
   on serie.id = doc.documento_serie_id
inner join documento_detail as det 
   on case when serie.documento_tipo_id = 15 then doc.source_id = det.documento_id else doc.id = det.documento_id end
inner join phos_iva as iva 
   on iva.id = det.iva_id
where serie.documento_categoria_id = 3  
  and doc.rascunho = false 
  and doc.exercicio_id = 4 
group by mes
order by mes
```